# Drupal 8 - Get current node id from controller

Tags: php, drupal, controller, drupal-8

I am building a Drupal 8 module with reactjs and I need to get the current node id from a controller so I can do certain tasks based on the node id but I always receive a null value, my routing is working correctly and my function is the following:

```
  public function currentNodeId()
    {
        // get current node
        $node_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->Id();

        return new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'node_id' => $node_id
            )
        );
    }
```

and in mymodule.routing.yml I have:

```
 mymodule-currentNode:
   path: '/mymodule/currentNodeId'
   defaults:
     _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::currentNodeId'
     _title: 'Current node id'
   requirements:
     _permission: 'access content'
```

I can get the current node id from my module file 'mymodule.module' doing the same I did in the currentNodeId function:

```
   $node_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->Id();
```

Anyone knows if this is some kind of security or am I doing anything wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by storing the current node id in a variable each time the module loads. You must have module cache disabled so the .module file can load each time.

More info here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229780/get-current-node-id-from-controller/229787#229787